# Clarification of the third-party software options during system installation

Tags: installation, wireless, flash, ubiquity, proprietary

During installation, the user is presented with the following dialogue:

[image]

The 'Flash' and 'MP3' options are pretty self-explanatory, but what about the 'wireless hardware' and 'other media' options. What 'other media' is this referring to, and how is the installation of wireless hardware handled. Does Ubiquity attempt to recognise the computer's wireless device and install the appropriate drivers or does it just dump a 'proprietary wireless driver module' into the kernel and be done with it? How does it react if the computer has no wireless card?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "Install this third-party software" checkbox does two things:

1. It installs `ubuntu-restricted-addons` much later on in the main install process.  This currently includes gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly, flashplugin-installer (Adobe Flash support), gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad, gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg, icedtea6-plugin (Java and the browser plugin for it), and gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 (MP3 playback support).
2. It asks the Additional Drivers (jockey) program to enable any drivers that can be automatically installed.  Currently this is limited to just the Broadcom wireless (binary) driver.

If the computer is not connected to the Internet, the install will complete successfully; however, the following will happen:

1. Your location will not be automatically determined on the 'Where are you?' page.
2. The set of locations you can look up by typing in the box on the 'Where are you?' page will be limited to just the cities that represent a timezone (Oslen database locations).
3. If you have checked the 'Download updates while installing' box, this step will be skipped.
4. If you have selected a language without full language support shipped on the CD, the language support packages will not be downloaded as part of the Ubuntu installation process.

Comment: Does Additional Drivers include NVIDIA as well?

Answer (score 4):

**Install This third-party software**
Third Party are ALL software that does not come normally recommended (100% free software) with Ubuntu in the CD/DVD. For example the Flash and MP3 are proprietary (Until a better software emerges which i have high hopes like Lightspark and Gnash). Wireless, Video and other proprietary drivers are also taken as a third party. They are in the repo like Nvidia and Broadcom but they are still proprietary. So basically if you install all Third Party it will include all the NEEDED drivers and software to have your Ubuntu running in top shape for any type of normal use.

The third party depends in what hardware you have for the third party drivers it will install. The rest of mp3, flash and such will always get installed.

I will add that wine is not in the third party since a standard user would not need to use this (Am not the standard ;) ).

If you select **Download Updates While Installing** it will search in the repositories for any update available up to that day.