# Third Party Software was not Installed

Tags: software-installation, ubiquity

I did a fresh install of UbuntuGNOME 13.10. During the installation, I had checked both the options for downloading updates and installing third-party softwares. But it seems that third-party softwares are not installed. I cannot play media files such as mp3, mp4 etc. Also, flash content cannot be played on websites. I'll install VLC to play media files. But, why was third-party softwares not installed? I have a working Internet connection.

Comment: (maybe) Because of your connection speed, package losting. You may want to report it as a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the below command on terminal(ctrl+alt+t) to install Ubuntu Restricted extras,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I know of ubuntu-restricted-extras. But I would like to know why third-party packages were not installed during installation even though I had checked the corresponding option.

Comment: it installs only ubuntu-restricted-addons and additional drivers.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/a/22291/202806

Comment: @sid - Avinash's commands do pretty much the same thing ;-)

Comment: I did a fresh install and things went smooth this time :)
But I know that answer by @AvinashRaj works beacuase I had done it earlier :)