# Hour + download of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I'm new to Linux, and thought it'd be interesting to try it out. I read through some forums on how to install and dual boot it properly. Although, I've been having issues during the installation process. Once I get to Updates and other software, and select what was recommended on the Ubuntu website, it just loads forever. I have slow internet, about 55Mbps, maybe that's what the hangup is. I really don't know, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your speed is faster than my *advertized* speed so it's not that slow (will depend on where you are in the world & what you can pay for of course), but there are many mirrors you can use around the world, some provide far faster support than others. I'd also ensure they are *up-to-date* (more critical to me than speed claim), so you can always try using a different mirrors. List of official mirrors is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors (don't use any *last update unknown* and try and avoid *days* behind.  My own is *6 hrs behind* but given it updates min. 4 times/day I'm okay with it

Answer (score 0):

Case 1) You have installed Ubuntu and then trying to update softwares:

In the resources tab of GNOME System Monitor, you can see the network usage.
There you can check, whether the network is really the issue.

Case 2) You are trying to install latest software updates during installation:

Do not do it during installation time, install it without updates. Once you have a fully working system, then try to update. You will be in a position to diagnose it better.

Could you please enlighten where on Ubuntu website is the list of recommended softwares that you have indicated.

Edit: Do not check "Install this third-party software" either, as this also downloads from internet.

Comment: Oh shit, I selected to download updates while installing. When it comes to the softwares question you have, there is a page during the installation called, "Updates and other softwares" and on the installation directs Ubuntu has on their website, which I can't find on my phone right now, it recommended to choose the "install the updates" and "install third party software options". I also have a follow up question, should I wait out this install, I am still on the same page as when I posted this question waiting for the install, or should I quit the installation?

Comment: I believe you should quit the installation and start again.

Comment: Do you believe I should tick the "install third-party software for graphics and WiFi hardware and additional media formats" box?

Comment: As given in https://askubuntu.com/a/22291/1107236 , it seems that the installer will try to download packages from internet. But will still complete if not connected to internet.
Since you already had a bad experience with the internet connectivity during installation, you better skip this. If WiFi is not working after installation, you can follow https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/

Comment: It was that! Thank you. Once I didn't use Wi-Fi and only ticked the "normal installation" box, it took a couple minutes. Man, I've wasted hours now, but it's done! Thank you. How did I mark your answer is the correct answer?

Comment: Just click the grey tick mark on left side of the post below the number zero, it should turn green :)

Comment: Im so sorry, I was preemptive. It helps, sometimes, and now my laptop freezes when it comes to allocating disk space. It just freezes.

Comment: Debugging this part can become a bit complicated. Try another time. If problem persists, you can ty to follow https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/ubuntu-freezes-during-installation/1595

Comment: Okay, it finally seems to have worked. I had to use the nomodeset and update the kernel after installing. I don't know what the source of the problem was, but this seemed to be the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Good to know that finally you could get it going.